# X11 forwarding - have window showing on two computers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, xorg

I currently have 2 desks: one with a mac, the other with a 2 Linux computers on.
One of those Linux computers is constantly on, so I would run the chat app on that (pidgin, most likely).
I can run pidgin on Mac by sshing into the Linux computer with "ssh -X", i.e. X11 forwarding. However, I want to have the chat windows viewable on both computers simultaneously (or at the very least, by entering a command or whatever).

Is this possible and if so, how?
(Also: I know that it'd be possible via VNC or whatever, but yuck - X11 on mac is bad enough.)

Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using VNC instead of X in this case. It's trivial to do with VNC, and what really is so "yuck" about it?

Comment: Unless you can show only windows with VNC, which I don't think you can, I'd prefer not to do it that way. Would take up too much space, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, what you want can't be done directly. I don't think you have an option outside of VNC or something else that talks X to the application and a point to multipoint protocol to your systems.